# How would one change the default url structure of attachments?

Tags: posts, images, attachments

When I click on post images it redirects in a page with a url like this: `http://localhost/?attachment_id=897`. Can I set the default image link like `http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/dice.jpg` instead of `http://localhost/?attachment_id=818`? Also how to style the attachments page? Should I have a page like attachments.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to: Dashboard -> Settings -> Media

Check this box: Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders.

Save changes.

then

Navigate to: Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks

Select "Post name" under "Common Settings"

Save changes.

As far as styling an attachment page, you can either open up your page template file, and add a conditional check for [is_attachment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_attachment) or you can make an attachment.php file in your template directory. [Read more about the template hierarchy for attachment display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Attachment_display).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments